# regex to match entire words containing mandatory and allowed characters

Tags: regex

I want to match entire words that containing mandatory chars and allowed chars.

For example
Mandatory chars are : [ c , a , t ]
Allowed chars are : [ y , s]

```
cat   : passed (all mandatories are here)
caty  : passed (all mandatories here and only allowed "y" char)
casy  : failed (mandatory 't' is absent)
catso : failed (all mandatories but an intruder "o")
```

What is the appropriate REGEX code for this?

Comment: do you know the mandatory and allowed chars in advance?

Comment: What language is that for? Not all regex flavors support lookaround.

Comment: catt will pass? and catyy?

Comment: @jbaylina `cassy` shouldn't pass since it lacks a `t`

Comment: Sorrt catyy? It's ok if repeated?

Comment: You may want to look into not using a regex at all, depending on how simple it is for the language you are using to iterate through the characters in a string.  Regexes can be fairly expensive, and your conditions are fairly easy to check by checking all characters (and noting if any mandatory characters are present).

Comment: No I dont know mandatory and allowed chars in advance they will be calculated then injected as parameters. 
Yes catt and catyy will pass and cassy will not. 
Yes i am looking this regex pattern for php and mysql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do that with this kind of pattern, if your regex flavor have the lookahead feature:

```
 \b(?=[a-z]*?c)(?=[a-z]*?a)(?=[a-z]*?t)[actys]+\b
```

Note that lookarounds can be expensive due to the backtracks. You can limit it using two tricks:

1) using more constraints for character classes:

```
\b(?=[a-bd-z]*c)(?=[b-z]*a)(?=[a-su-z]*t)[actys]+\b
```

2) using possessive quantifiers (if supported)

```
\b(?=[a-bd-z]*+c)(?=[b-z]*+a)(?=[a-su-z]*+t)[actys]++\b
```

or atomic groups in place of:

```
\b(?=(?>[a-bd-z]*)c)(?=(?>[b-z]*)a)(?=(?>[a-su-z]*)t)(?>[actys]+)\b
```

Comment: You should move the first word boundary before the first lookahead. Then, +1 ;)

Comment: @TimPietzcker why? There is performance impact here, but that's about all

Comment: After a quick test, it seems to be the same, you can put it everywhere like other zero-width assertions.

Comment: There are 12.000 rows containing single words in a MySQL table to make this REGEX search in a PHP project. So which approach should I choose?

Comment: @OzgurEffe: If i were you, i will make some test (with a timer) to compare, (the regex in php and a SELECT * query) with (muliple WHERE LIKE clauses or other) and with (an hybrid way: one or two LIKE clauses and regex in php with less conditions)

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yes, just because of the (potential) performance impact. Both regexes would match the same, but if you anchor the search to the word boundary before trying all those lookaheads, you avoid a lot of fruitless match attempts, i. e. with the string `bobcat`, the lookaheads are each attempted four times (first on `bobcat`, then on `obcat`, then on `bcat`, and then on `cat`), and only then the word boundary is checked (which even succeeds in the first case, but then the `b` fails quickly). A clever regex engine might optimize this away, but I don't know if PHP's engine is that clever.

Answer (score 1):

try this one and tell me if it needs any enhancements:

```
/^ca[t]+[ys]*$/i
```